Issue with scipy.fft in a robust_gauss_fft filter
I have been developing a Robust Gaussian Filter in Python following the Ref. doi:10.1088/0957-0233/21/5/055108 method.
The spatial domain implementation of the filter was successful but slow for large images. I implemented the FFT domain version in C++ and it worked. Now, I am trying to implement the same code in Python and I get very different results. Here is my code:
# Robust areal_gaussian regression filter based on following references:
# (1) ISO16610-71 Geometrical product specifications (GPS) — Filtration — Part 71: Robust areal filters: Gaussian regression filters
# (2) Fast algorithm of the robust Gaussian regression filter for areal surface analysis doi:10.1088/0957-0233/21/5/055108

# %%
# ----------- external libraries -----------
import os
import cv2
import time
import logging
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy import fft

# ----------- constants and logging settigns -----------
FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT)
kernel_g_x = np.zeros((10))
hp_cutoff = 31
directory = os.getcwd()

# ----------- robust_gauss in spatial domain -----------
def robust_gauss(z, lambda_c, order=0, iter_max=3):
    """
    robust areal gaussian regression filter
    Code based on pseudo code from Ref2 -Section 4.3 
    Parameters
    ----------
    inputs:
    z: ndarray of height data
    lambda_c: (nesting index) cut-off wavelength in pixels 
    (it will be attenuated by 50%) 
    sigma = (lambda_c/pi) * sqrt(log(2)/2)
    lambda_c = (sigma*pi) / sqrt(log(2)/2)
    order: filter order
    
    outputs:
    w: ndarray of waviness surface (Lambda>Lambda_c low-pass surface)
    r: ndarray of roughness surface (Lambda<Lambda_c high-pass surface)
    """
    start = time.time()
    a,b=z.shape
    logging.debug(f'Init.')
    logging.debug(f'--Filter order: {order}')
    logging.debug(f'--Array size: {a}x{b}')
    
    global kernel_g_x
    global kernel_g_y
    
    #calculate sigma from lambda
    #50% attentuation at lambda
    kernel_g_x=gauss_kernel1d((lambda_c/np.pi)*np.sqrt(np.log(2)/2))
    kernel_g_y=gauss_kernel1d((lambda_c/np.pi)*np.sqrt(np.log(2)/2))
    
    #code based on pseudo code from Ref2 -Section 4.3                     
    #init delta
    delta = np.ones_like(z,dtype=float)
    w = np.zeros_like(z,dtype=float)
    r = np.zeros_like(z,dtype=float)
    
    cb0 = 1
    # track the values of stop criteria for debugging
    stop_arr=np.array(1)

    #iteration counter
    iter=0

    while True:
        iter=iter+1;
        logging.debug(f'--Iteration: {iter}')
        
        A = calculateA_fast(delta,order)
        F = calculateF_fast(delta,z,order)
        
        w = solve_linear_equations(A,F,z,order)
        # residual surface
        r= z - w
        
        #MAD 
        cb1 = 4.478*np.median(np.abs(r))

        #exit if close enough
        stop = abs((cb0-cb1)/(cb0+1E-10))

        stop_arr = np.append(stop_arr,stop)
        if stop < 0.001 or iter >= iter_max:
            break

        delta = _update_delta(r,cb1)
        cb0=cb1
    logging.debug(f'done. elapsed time: {time.time()-start}s ')
    return w,r,cb1

def conv_scaled_gauss(data, i, j):
    """
    Calculate convolution of input data with n-th order areal gaussian kernel
    out = (data conv x^i*1d_gauss) conv y^j*1d_gauss)
    """
    global kernel_g_x
    global kernel_g_y
   
    out = np.zeros_like(data)
    
    #calculate n-th order kernels for x and y axis
    kernel_x = np.multiply(kernel_g_x, (np.arange(len(kernel_g_x)) - (len(kernel_g_x)-1)/2)**i)
    kernel_y = np.multiply(kernel_g_y, (np.arange(len(kernel_g_y)) - (len(kernel_g_y)-1)/2)**j)
    
    #convolve in x direction
    out = ndimage.convolve1d(data, kernel_x, 1, mode='constant') 
    out = ndimage.convolve1d(out, kernel_y, 0, mode='constant') 
    
    return out

# Ref2 - eq.19
def calculateAij_fast(delta, i, j):
    Aij = conv_scaled_gauss(delta,i,j)
    return Aij
    
def calculateA_fast(delta, order):
    if order == 0:
        A00 = calculateAij_fast(delta, 0, 0)
        A = A00
    elif order == 1:
        A00 = calculateAij_fast(delta, 0, 0)
        A10 = calculateAij_fast(delta, 1, 0)
        A01 = calculateAij_fast(delta, 0, 1)
        A20 = calculateAij_fast(delta, 2, 0)
        A11 = calculateAij_fast(delta, 1, 1)
        A02 = calculateAij_fast(delta, 0, 2)
        # assemble A matrix
        A = np.array([[A00, A10, A01],
                       [A10, A20, A11],
                       [A01, A11, A02]])
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unsupported filter order. Supporting following orders: 0, 1, 2')
        logging.debug("calculate A end ")
    
    return A

# Ref eq.20
def calculateFij_fast(delta, z, i, j):
    F = conv_scaled_gauss(delta*z,i,j)
    return F
                         
def calculateF_fast(delta,z,order):
    if order == 0:
        F00 = calculateFij_fast(delta, z, 0, 0)
        F = F00
    elif order==1:
        F00 = calculateFij_fast(delta, z, 0, 0)
        F10 = calculateFij_fast(delta, z, 1, 0)
        F01 = calculateFij_fast(delta, z, 0, 1)
        F = np.array([[F00], 
                        [F10], 
                        [F01]])
    return F

def _update_delta(r, c):
    idb = r > c
    ids = r < -c
    out = (1 - (r / c) ** 2) ** 2
    out[idb] = 0
    out[ids] = 0
    return out

def solve_linear_equations(A,F,z,order):
    # order 0 is simple, but have to handle the 0 in A
    # effectively we keep the z surface unchanged in areas where
    # the delta gets set to 0, thus preserving features without any distortion!                 
        
    w=np.zeros_like
    
    if order==0:
        l,k = A.shape
        A_m = np.ma.array(A,mask=A==0)
        w = F/A_m
        w[A_m.mask] = z[A_m.mask]
    elif order==1:
        l,k = A[0,0].shape
        out = np.zeros((3,1,l,k))
        for i in range(k):
            for j in range(l):
                out[:,:,j,i]= np.linalg.solve(A[:,:,j,i],F[:,:,j,i])
        w = out[0,0]        

    return w

def gauss_kernel1d(sigma:float):
    """
    Computes a 1D Gaussian convolution kernel. Radius set to 4*sigma +0.5.
    """
    sigma = float(sigma)
     
    #set kernel radius to 4 sigma
    radius = int(4*sigma + 0.5)
    
    sigma2 = sigma * sigma
    x = np.arange(-radius, radius+1)
    kernel_1d = np.exp(-0.5 / sigma2 * x ** 2)
    kernel_1d = kernel_1d / kernel_1d.sum()
    
    return kernel_1d

# -----------  robust_gauss in FFT domain -----------
def robust_gauss_fft(
    z: np.ndarray, 
    lambda_c: float, 
    order: int = 0, 
    iter_max: int = 3,
):    
    """
        robust gaussian regression filter in fft domain
        Code based on pseudo code from Ref2 -Section 4.3 and Section 4.2
    
    Args:
        z <ndarray> of height data
        lambda_c: <nesting index> cut-off wavelength in pixels (it will be attenuated by 50%) 
        sigma: <float> = (lambda_c/pi) * sqrt(log(2)/2)
        lambda_c: <float> = (sigma*pi) / sqrt(log(2)/2)
        order: <int> filter order
    
    Returns:
        w: <ndarray> of waviness surface (Lambda>Lambda_c low-pass surface)
        r: <ndarray> of roughness surface (Lambda<Lambda_c high-pass surface)
    """
    start = time.time()
    a,b = z.shape
    logging.debug(f'Init.')
    logging.debug(f'--Filter order: {order}')
    logging.debug(f'--Array size: {a}x{b}')
    
    global kernel_g_x
        
    #calculate sigma from lambda (50% attentuation at lambda)
    kernel_g_x = gauss_kernel1d((lambda_c/np.pi)*np.sqrt(np.log(2)/2))
    
    # code based on pseudo code from Ref2 -Section 4.3                     
    # init delta
    delta = np.ones_like(z, dtype=float)
    w = np.zeros_like(z, dtype=float)
    r = np.zeros_like(z, dtype=float)
    
    cb0 = 1
    #track the values of stop criteria for debugging
    stop_arr=np.array(1)

    #iteration counter
    iter=0
    
    num_y, num_x = z.shape
    kern_len = len(kernel_g_x)
    bandx = np.arange(int((num_x-kern_len)/2), int((num_x-kern_len)/2) + kern_len, 1)
    bandy = np.arange(int((num_y-kern_len)/2), int((num_y-kern_len)/2) + kern_len, 1)
    ft_xys = {}
    if order == 0:
        x0sx = calculate_ft_api_sa(kernel_g_x, 0)
        # zero-pad to match size of arrays
        ft_x0sx = np.zeros((num_y,num_x))
        ft_x0sx[:, bandx] = x0sx.copy()
        ft_y0sy = np.zeros((num_x,num_y))
        ft_y0sy[:, bandy] = x0sx.copy()
        ft_y0sy = (ft_y0sy.T).copy()
        ft_xys["ft_x0sx"] = ft_x0sx
        ft_xys["ft_y0sy"] = ft_y0sy
    elif order == 1:
        x0sx = calculate_ft_api_sa(kernel_g_x, 0)
        # zero-pad to match size of arrays
        ft_x0sx = np.zeros((num_y,num_x))
        ft_x0sx[:, bandx] = x0sx.copy()
        ft_y0sy = np.zeros((num_x,num_y))
        ft_y0sy[:, bandy] = x0sx.copy()
        ft_y0sy = (ft_y0sy.T).copy()
        ft_xys["ft_x0sx"] = ft_x0sx
        ft_xys["ft_y0sy"] = ft_y0sy
        
        x1sx = calculate_ft_api_sa(kernel_g_x, 1)
        # zero-pad to match size of arrays
        ft_x1sx = np.zeros((num_y,num_x))
        ft_x1sx[:, bandx] = x1sx.copy()
        ft_y1sy = np.zeros((num_x,num_y))
        ft_y1sy[:, bandy] = x1sx.copy()
        ft_y1sy = (ft_y1sy.T).copy()
        ft_xys["ft_x1sx"] = ft_x1sx
        ft_xys["ft_y1sy"] = ft_y1sy
        
        x2sx = calculate_ft_api_sa(kernel_g_x, 2)
        # zero-pad to match size of arrays
        ft_x2sx = np.zeros((num_y,num_x))
        ft_x2sx[:, bandx] = x2sx.copy()
        ft_y2sy = np.zeros((num_x,num_y))
        ft_y2sy[:, bandy] = x2sx.copy()
        ft_y2sy = (ft_y2sy.T).copy()
        ft_xys["ft_x2sx"] = ft_x2sx
        ft_xys["ft_y2sy"] = ft_y2sy
        
    while True:
        iter = iter+1
        logging.debug(f'--Iteration: {iter}')
        
        A, F = calculate_A_n_F(delta, z, order, ft_xys)
        
        w = solve_linear_equations(A, F, z, order)
        # residual surface
        r= z - w

        # MAD 
        cb1 = 4.478*np.median(np.abs(r))

        # exit if close enough
        stop = abs((cb0-cb1)/(cb0+1E-10))

        stop_arr = np.append(stop_arr,stop)
        if stop < 0.001 or iter >= iter_max:
            break

        delta = _update_delta(r,cb1)
        cb0=cb1
    logging.debug(f'rar_gauss_fft done. elapsed time: {time.time()-start}s ')
    
    return w,r,cb1

def calculate_A_n_F(delta, z, order, ft_xys):
    if order == 0:
        A00 = calculate_A(delta, ft_xys["ft_x0sx"], ft_xys["ft_y0sy"])
        F00 = calculate_F(delta, z, ft_xys["ft_x0sx"], ft_xys["ft_y0sy"])
        out = (A00, F00)
    elif order == 1:        
        A00 = calculate_A(delta, ft_xys["ft_x0sx"], ft_xys["ft_y0sy"])
        A10 = calculate_A(delta, ft_xys["ft_x1sx"], ft_xys["ft_y0sy"])
        A01 = calculate_A(delta, ft_xys["ft_x0sx"], ft_xys["ft_y1sy"])
        A20 = calculate_A(delta, ft_xys["ft_x2sx"], ft_xys["ft_y0sy"])
        A11 = calculate_A(delta, ft_xys["ft_x1sx"], ft_xys["ft_y1sy"])
        A02 = calculate_A(delta, ft_xys["ft_x0sx"], ft_xys["ft_y2sy"])
        # assemble A matrix
        A = np.array([[A00, A10, A01],
                      [A10, A20, A11],
                      [A01, A11, A02]])
        F00 = calculate_F(delta, z, ft_xys["ft_x0sx"], ft_xys["ft_y0sy"])
        F10 = calculate_F(delta, z, ft_xys["ft_x1sx"], ft_xys["ft_y0sy"])
        F01 = calculate_F(delta, z, ft_xys["ft_x0sx"], ft_xys["ft_y1sy"])
        # assemble F matrix
        F = np.array([[F00],
                      [F10],
                      [F01]])
        out = (A, F)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unsupported filter order. Supporting following orders: 0, 1')
        logging.debug("calculate A end ")
    
    return out

def calculate_ft_api_sa(sa, i):
    # api_sa = np.multiply(sa, (np.arange(len(sa)))**i)
    api_sa = np.multiply(sa, (np.arange(len(sa)) - (len(sa)-1)/2)**i)
    ft_api_sa = np.array(fft.fft(api_sa))

    return ft_api_sa

def calculate_A(delta, ft_x_i_sx, ft_y_j_sy):
    ft_delta_x = np.array(fft.fft(delta, axis=1))
    ift_ft_delta_x_ft_x_i_sx = np.array(fft.ifft(np.multiply(ft_delta_x , ft_x_i_sx), axis=1))
    ft_ift_ft_delta_x_ft_x_i_sx = np.array(fft.fft(ift_ft_delta_x_ft_x_i_sx, axis=0))
    result = np.array(fft.ifft(np.multiply(ft_ift_ft_delta_x_ft_x_i_sx, ft_y_j_sy), axis=0))
    
    return result.real  # Return real part as the result should be real-valued

def calculate_F(delta, z, ft_x_i_sx, ft_y_j_sy):
    ft_delta_z_x = np.array(fft.fft(np.multiply(z, delta), axis=1))
    ift_ft_delta_z_x_ft_x_i_sx = np.array(fft.ifft(np.multiply(ft_delta_z_x, ft_x_i_sx), axis=1))
    ft_ift_ft_delta_z_x_ft_x_i_sx = np.array(fft.fft(ift_ft_delta_z_x_ft_x_i_sx, axis=0))
    result = np.array(fft.ifft(np.multiply(ft_ift_ft_delta_z_x_ft_x_i_sx, ft_y_j_sy), axis=0))
    
    return result.real # Return real part as the result should be real-valued


def make_save_heatmap(
    image_name,
    data,
):
    colormap = plt.get_cmap("plasma")
    temp_norm = np.zeros((data.shape), "float64")
    temp_norm = cv2.normalize(data, temp_norm, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    temp_norm_save = temp_norm.astype("uint8")
    heatmap = (colormap(temp_norm_save) * 2 ** 16).astype(np.uint16)[:, :, :3]
    temp_norm_hm = cv2.cvtColor(heatmap, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite(image_name, temp_norm_hm)
    
# ----------- main code -----------
sample_name = "test_image"
file_path = str(directory)+'/'+"test_image.png"
image = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
image = image[:, :, 0].copy()

lp_image_fft, hp_image_fft, mad_val_fft = robust_gauss_fft(image.copy(), lambda_c=hp_cutoff, order=0, iter_max=3)
make_save_heatmap(f"{directory}/{sample_name}_hp_fft.png", hp_image_fft)

lp_image, hp_image, mad_val = robust_gauss(image.copy(), lambda_c=hp_cutoff, order=0, iter_max=3)
make_save_heatmap(f"{directory}/{sample_name}_hp.png", hp_image)

Here is the image for testing the code:

Here is the spatial robust_gauss() filter result:

Here is the robust_gauss_fft() result which is all zeros:

Any help on debugging this issue is appreciated. I think I have implemented all the parts of the filter properly, but I am missing something in the scipy.fft library probably.

Do you need to implement fft convolution at all? SciPy already has an FFT convolution implementation. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html
